# Amazon SSL certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I try to assign SSL certificate for my domain. I have created a www.domain.com certificate and assigned it to my elastic beanstalk; and it works really fine as I can see a little green lock next to my domain if I access with https://www.domain.com or www.domain.com. The problem is that when I try to access by domain.com, the lock is gone. Can anyone suggest what I should do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get a new certificate for both www and non-www domain when you request the certificate there is option check below screenshot. And then you force the https on the application. And your site will serve through SSL certificate for both domains www and non www.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more about forcing the https on the application please?

Comment: Forcing SSL is some thing that you do from the web server side. But first the SSL certificate should be for both domain. What web server are you using?